# How To Get Total To 2 Decimals With Textbox/Messagebox (VS2017)

Tags: textbox, decimal

So basically, I have 4 text boxes, user then enters numbers into the 4 textboxes, then you press the calculate button and it pops up a text box "Player has run ___ km"

Thats all fine, and it then shows in the total text box too.

But if I enter a decimal (e.g. 10, 10.2, 10.01, 10) it'd only say 40, not 40.21. (or even to 1 decimal).

How could I edit it to show to 2 decimals in the textbox and messagebox?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you show your code, it will be easier for others to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user2653663 Didn't know it was necessary for this question but here

Comment: Dim quarter4 As Integer
        quarter4 = TextBox4.Text
        Dim quarter3 As Integer
        quarter3 = TextBox3.Text
        Dim quarter2 As Integer
        quarter2 = TextBox2.Text
        Dim quarter1 As Integer
        quarter1 = TextBox1.Text
        TotalDis.Text = quarter1 + quarter2 + quarter3 + quarter4
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox6.Text & " has run " & TotalDis.Text & " km this season")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change dimming the quarters to integers, to dimming them to double.

So it looks like

```
        Dim quarter4 As Double
        quarter4 = TextBox4.Text
        Dim quarter3 As Double
        quarter3 = TextBox3.Text
        Dim quarter2 As Double
        quarter2 = TextBox2.Text
        Dim quarter1 As Double
        quarter1 = TextBox1.Text
        TotalDis.Text = quarter1 + quarter2 + quarter3 + quarter4
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox6.Text & " has run " & TotalDis.Text & " km this season")
```